# Reset my google cloud VM instances, but the External IP is changed, why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I stop the instance yesterday , and today I start it. 
The external Ip is changed, I don't know why they do that , how can I get my ip back?

Comment: As stated in the documentation "When you create a VM instance, it is automatically assigned an ephemeral external IP address. If you don't want an ephemeral external IP address, you can explicitly assign a static external IP address to the instance instead." https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. As Paula says, you were assigned an ephemeral IP address, which is gone when you stop the machine.

If you don't want to lose it upon stopping the machine, you need to reserve the IP address, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

Comment: Does GCP assign ephemeral external IP addresses in some cases? Can you tell how I can achieve that (under which conditions)? Can't find the relevant info.

Comment: It appears it does. With `terraform` that'll be when `google_compute_instance.network_interface.access_config.nat_ip` is left unspecified.