# Restart VM Instance in Google Cloud After Clicking "Stop"

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I am having a mild panic attack and could use some help.

I was emailed by Google telling me I need to change my machine type in my VM Instance. So I logged in, it told me I needed to stop the instance to make that change. I stopped the instance and then realized I'm not using the deprecated F1-Micro, so I just hit Play to restart the instance.

It restarts, has the reassuring green symbol, but my wordpress site can't be accessed.

I tried connecting via SSH and it seems like the data is there, I can navigate to the wordpress folder.

Can someone please advise on what I need to do to get the site running?

Thanks!

EDIT: More Info

1. Checking status of NGINX server shows it is "active (running)"
2. When visiting the web address, it loads for a very long time and then goes to an error page that just says "This site can't be reached the site took too long to respond. try checking connection and the proxy and the firewall. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: "site can't be accessed" what error do you get? and is your web server (e.g NGINX) running?

Comment: thanks for the response.  For the site is just says "site can't be reached". How do I check if the server is running? So I guess after it stops I need to run some more commands to get it going again, that makes sense. I will look into that.

Comment: I checked nginx status and it says its running. :-/

Comment: Marking this as duplicate of this one since actually this is very frequent issue and is asked frequently [Reset my google cloud VM instances, but the External IP is changed, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912372/reset-my-google-cloud-vm-instances-but-the-external-ip-is-changed-why)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

The Google documentation suggests your IP address will remain. Whether that is standard or not, my IP address changed, so once I updated my DNS records I was back online.

Comment: That means your external IP address for that instance is not static. You need to get a external static IP address.